# Trying to use CSS Multiple Checkbox Hack on Same Page

Tags: css, html, checkbox

I'm trying to utilize the CSS checkbox hack to toggle Display:None and Display:Block for multiple sections of one page. I have image gallery sets split by year and starting hidden, and would like to be able to click the year to toggle that specific gallery's display. The point I'm stuck at is whenever I click one of the labels, everything below it toggles, not just the section contained within the  tag I'm trying to specifically toggle.

Here is what I have so far.

CSS Code

```
.hide {
    display:none;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .hide {
    display:block;
}

label {
    display: block;
    background: white;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 0px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

And the HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle_2012">
<label for="toggle_2012">2012</label><br>
<div class="hide">
<a class="fancybox" rel="2012" href="imgs/fb/3_b.jpg"><img src="imgs/fb/3_s.jpg" alt="Image 3"/></a> 
<a class="fancybox" rel="2012" href="imgs/fb/4_b.jpg"><img src="imgs/fb/4_s.jpg" alt="Image 4"/></a> 
</div>

<input type="checkbox" id="toggle_2013">
<label for="toggle_2013">2013</label><br>
<div class="hide">
<a class="fancybox" rel="2013" href="imgs/fb/1_b.jpg"><img src="imgs/fb/1_s.jpg" alt="Image 1"/></a>
<a class="fancybox" rel="2013" href="imgs/fb/2_b.jpg"><img src="imgs/fb/2_s.jpg" alt="Image 2"/></a> 
</div>
```

(Jquery/Fancybox is being used to display the images, which is why they are classed for Fancybox)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is my first time working with the checkbox hack, but to my understanding having unique ID's for the input/label should work. Not sure what I'm missing here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your [css selector ~](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_gen_sibling.asp) affects every following element with that class. try:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label + .hide
```

you may have to remove the `<br>` for this to work.

Comment: Clever way to avoid hardcoding to an ID! +1

Answer (score -1):

This is a few months on, and possibly you found your solution by now, but for the benefit of anyone finding this thread, here's my solution. Firstly, You were correct in giving the checkbox an ID (CLASS would also work in some situations), however you must actually reference that ID in your CSS.

Instead of:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .hide {
    display:block;
}
```

Try this:

```
#toggle_2013:checked ~ .hide {
    display:block;
}
```

Without specifically identifying the checkbox in your CSS aswell as in the HTML, the first suitable checkbox in the DOM will be activated rather than the one you want.

Hope this helps.